# Nested query denormalization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve a list with all items available for the current user?

In my app a user can store multiple freezers and share those freezers with others.

Under each freezer they can make categories for sorting their items. And then finally under each category they store their items.

With my database structure it is easy to show, a list of freezers then a list of categories based on chosen freezer and finally a list of items based on the current category. But I would like a list of all items available to the user, without him or her choosing any freezer or category first.

How do I restructure my database?

I have this database tree

```
{
"userFreezer" : {
    "userMail" : {
      "Freezer Id " : {
        "fryserCreator" : "Anders Sund-jensen",
        "fryserNavn" : "fryser"
      },
      "Freezer Id 2" : {
        "fryserCreator" : "Anders Sund-jensen",
        "fryserNavn" : "test"
      }
    },
    "userEmail2" : {
      "Freezer Id" : {
        "fryserCreator" : "Anders Sund-jensen",
        "fryserNavn" : "fryser"
      }
    }
  },
"SharedFreezer": {
      "Freezer Id" : {
            "User Email" : { 
                  "User" = data }
                         }
             }

"category" : {
    "Freezer Id" : {
      "category Id" : {
        "kategoriCreator" : "Anders Sund-jensen",
        "kategoriNavn" : "Fisk"
      }
    }
  },
  "Varer": {
    "Category Id" : {
      "Item" : {
        "enhed" : "spsk",
        "vareDag" : 31,
        "vareMåned" : 7,
        "vareNavn" : "derp",
        "vareTime" : 1504218176660,
        "vareVægt" : 500,
        "vareÅr" : 2017
      } "Item 2" {
         ...}
    }
  }
```

As asked before I want a full list of items available for the current user and that requires a whole lot of ids and nested queries which isn't synchronized so therefore I don't know when that list of ids would be finished downloading.

The app also has a sharing function which makes it unable to save the items under a user's email.

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the response and sorry for not making it clear. found out i did a translate issue so the database tree looked weird. I updated the question with a better description of my problem and editted the translate issue.